# Back pain chart

Tags: back-pain, lower-back, back

Is there a chart describing via a figure or set of figures, with explanations, the different kinds of back pain one can experience and their causes?

What about medical computer simulations, depicting accidents, pain visually, and a set of remedies, including a set of steps and procedures the massage therapist can use, from which one can learn to become a therapist.

People can simulate driving through a computer, I see no reason why one could not sinulate an accident and giving a massage through a computer.

We already have crash-test-dummies, to simulate the injury. We need to combine this with pain models, and pain elimination techniques, models for simulating physical activities of injured people, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes there are back pain charts.](https://www.google.no/search?q=back+pain+chart&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyvoCQor7OAhVjP5oKHTq9Ca4QsAQIHQ&biw=1920&bih=995) But in the grand scheme of things, any such chart is going to have a lot of missing information, because there is simply too many types of back pain to put onto a single chart.

For the rest of the question, I don't see what you're trying to ask. It looks like you're just speculating about whether or not there exists injury simulation software, and that falls outside the scope of this StackExchange.

Please read the [on-topic guide](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.